# Geopandas errors when using ".within()" in an if statement

Tags: python, geopandas

I have three dataframes I am working with and want to do the following logic:

if dataframe1 in not within dataframe2 but is within dataframe3 then do something

first attempt was:

```
if df1['geometry'].within(df2['geometry']) == False & df1['geometry'].within(df3['geometry']) == True:
    continue with code
```

and I got the error:

```
The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all() using panda python
```

so I tried:

```
if df1['geometry'].within(df2['geometry']).any() == False & df1['geometry'].within(df3['geometry']).any() == True:
    continue with code
```

and I get the error:

```
TypeError: 'GeoDataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

I'm not sure what to do to fix this

update:

tried

```
if df1['geometry'].any().within(df2['geometry']).any() == False & df1['geometry'].any().within(df3['geometry']).any() == True:
    continue with code
```

and I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'GeoSeries' object has no attribute '_geom'
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to compare a `boolean` to either `False` or `True`. For example, this statement:

```py
df1['geometry'].within(df2['geometry']).any() == False
```

can be written as follows:

```py
~df1['geometry'].within(df2['geometry']).any()
```

The tilde `~` operator works as a `not` here.

Taking this into account, you could try running the following code:

```py
if ~df1['geometry'].within(df2['geometry']).any() & df1['geometry'].within(df3['geometry']).any():
    continue with code
```

Answer (score 0):

Think I figured it out. I could also used @Marcelo Villa-Piñeros's advice to make it cleaner

just looking at

```
df1.geometry.within(df2.geometry.any())
```

I get an output of:

```
0    False
dtype: bool
```

So I need to get the bool at [0]

```
if df1.geometry.within(df2.geometry.any())[0] == False & df1.geometry.within(df3.geometry.any())[0] ==True:
       continue code
```